# How to stop overlapping click when run on change checkbox in table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have table with first column with checkbox.

I can select row by ticking checkbox and click on row in everywhere.

```
<form class=".form">
    <table class="table">
        <tbody>
            <tr data-id="1" >
                <td>
                <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="radio_1" value="1">
                <label for="radio_1"></label>
                </td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="2" >
                <td>
                <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="radio_2" value="2">
                <label for="radio_2"></label>
                </td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```

Checkbox change event:

```
$(document).on("change", "input[name=\"ids[]\"]", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // change the colour of row.
});
```

Table row click event:

```
$(document).on('click', '.form > table > tbody > tr', function() {
    $(this).find("input[name=\"ids[]\"]").trigger("click");
});
```

When i click toggle on row, checkbox is checked and unchecked working.
But i click on checkbox nothing is happen because both event is fired, like first ticked by change and then unchecked automatically by row click.

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: You could stop propagation in the checkbox event handler; you could check if the event originated from a checkbox in the row handler; or you could just have the row handler and throw the checkbox one away.

Comment: Use `event.stopPropagation()`

Comment: `$(document).on("change", ".checkbox", function(event) { event.stopPropagation(); // change the colour of row.});` It is not working.

Comment: Give us an example of your code along with a piece of html

Comment: @AksJacoves Description updated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the `change` event to `click` as below:

```js
$(document).on("click", "input[name=\"ids[]\"]", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    // change the colour of row.
});

$(document).on('click', 'form > table > tbody > tr', function() {
    $(this).find("input[name=\"ids[]\"]").trigger("click");
    console.log('clicked on row')
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form class=".form">
    <table class="table" border="1">
        <tbody>
            <tr data-id="1" >
                <td>
                <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="radio_1" value="1">
                <label for="radio_1"></label>
                </td>
                <td>1</td>
            </tr>
            <tr data-id="2" >
                <td>
                <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="ids[]" id="radio_2" value="2">
                <label for="radio_2"></label>
                </td>
                <td>2</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
```